# convert PHP exceptions to Laravel 5?

Tags: php, laravel-5

I ave Paypal IPN class and I am getting an error , because i have this line of code :

```
  throw new Exception("No POST data found.");
```

how do I convert this to laravel5 using my

```
App\Exceptions\Handle.php
```

Can anyone help me?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

add back-slash "\" before class name "Exception" (`throw new \Exception("No POST data found.");`). You do not have to convert it to anything.